# use str() inside {% %} django

Tags: django, django-templates

i try to compare object to a string within {% %} with str()  but not working .
cause when i do type(room.status)  = class main.models.status

```
{% if 'str(room.status)' == "Vacant" %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-dark btn-lg"> check in </button>

{% elif room.status == 'Occupied' %}                           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"> Check out </button>
{% elif room.status == 'Reserve' %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-outline-dark btn-lg"> Reserve in </button>

{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-outline-dark btn-lg">  Check status </button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can write a method in your model that returns a string version of what you want to compare with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) for this.

Write you template tag as:

```
@register.filter
def string_value(status):
    return str(status) #or room.status depending on what room is
```

And use it in your template as:

```
{{ room.status | string_value }}
```